# Non-equivalence of norms.

Tags: general-topology

What ways to prove the non equivalence of two norms? Is it sufficient to find a sequence associated to the two norms and having two different limits to prove the non equivalence?

Comment: Another way is to find a sequence having a limit in one of the norms, but no limit at all in the other norm.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is sufficient. If $X$ is a vector space with two equivalent norms $| \cdot |$ and $\| \cdot \|$ then $| x_n - x | \to 0$ implies $\| x_n - x \| \to 0$, i.e. the limits must be equal. (More fundamental: A sequence is Cauchy in both norms simultaneously.)

An easier criterion to verify non-equivalence of norms is usually the construction of a sequence which is bounded in one, but unbounded in the other norm: If there is a sequence $(x_n)$ and $M > 0$ such that $| x_n | \leq M$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$ but $\| x_n \| \to \infty$ then there cannot exist a $C > 0$ such that $\| \cdot \| \leq C | \cdot |$.

Comment: By bounded you mean it tends to a finite limit right?

Comment: I don’t think that @Three.OneFour means that at all.

Comment: Can i have an example for the unbounded sequences?

Comment: @MohamadMisto No: bounded means that $\{\|x_n\|:n\ge0\}$ is a bounded set of reals.

Comment: I added another sentence to clarify what I meant. Boundedness, which is usually understood as @egreg defined it, doesn't require the sequence to converge (nor the sequence of norms).